# Receiving Keypresses While in Background

Tags: c++, winapi

I am working on a Win32 application using winapi and I am curious as to if there is a way to receive keyboard events while the application is out of focus/windowless.

Originally I was reading the application message queue and checking for the `WM_KEYDOWN` message, however messages are only sent to the application while the window is in focus. I am aware that DirectInput can be used, but if possible I would like to avoid making my application require DirectX.

Is there any other way to receive keyboard presses while the window is out of focus other than using DirectInput?

Edit: No, before you ask I am not writing a keylogger. The application needs to respond to certain re-bindable keyboard shortcuts while in the background.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is directly supported by the winapi, you'll want to use [RegisterHotKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The *best* way you can achieve such behaviour is to hook the keyboard.

This is a handy tutorial explaining the basics: <kbd>[codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/system/keyboard/article.php/c5699/Hooking-the-Keyboard.htm)</kbd>
It also differentiates the hook types into *systemwide* and *process specific*.

Answer (score 0):

**Later edit: if the window is out of focus, it can't process `WM_KEYDOWN` messages even if `WM_KILLFOCUS` is ignored. Therefore you need to check regularly and separately for `GetAsyncKeyState()`.**

You could bypass the `WM_KILLFOCUS` in your `WndProc()` message so that the app doesn't go out of focus. It can still process any key press.

Something like:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWindow, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    switch (msg)
    {

    /* cases blah blah */

    case WM_KILLFOCUS:
        return 0;

    /* other cases' blah blah */

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWindow, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Actually, that would be easier. But is it safe? What if another app tries to gain focus?

Comment: Wouldn't this then prevent any other application from gaining focus? The idea is that the application should be able to receive keypresses while in the background as other applications run normally.

Comment: @Bad Wolf You should hook the keyboard. Wandering in the land of unknown behaviour isn't ideal.

Comment: @Bad Wolf: It doesn't prevent any app to gain focus. I have this example of my window and Chrome and when I click RMB Chrome does whatever it does on RMB and my app does what I told it to do on RMB
@TheOtherGuy it shouldn't be `break;` since it would return `DefWindowProc()` and we don't want that

Comment: @losif M. Is there any documentation backing that up? Because as far as I knew when I used windows, only one app was focused at a time.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy Yes, only one app can be focused. However, `WM_KILLFOCUS` (as per MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646282(v=vs.85).aspx) is "sent to a window immediately before it loses the **keyboard** focus". This means that input is still active if the message is ignored.
I advise Bad Wolf to experiment with both and see which one fits his needs better. Personally, I've used both hooks and `WM_KILLFOCUS`, but for what I needed, `WM_KILLFOCUS` was more than enough.

Comment: I've updated the answer (seems that I knew something from the day, but not the whole picture).

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft DirectX library contains a function that can be used to get the state of the keyboard. It is part of the DirectInput API. The code below demonstrates how to poll the keyboard for key state information. Additional logic would have to be added to detect when keys are pressed/released and to convert this to a character.

Note that this requires the Microsoft DirectX SDK to compile.

```
//Public domain: no attribution required
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "dxlog.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "dinput8")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxguid")

LPDIRECTINPUT8 din;
LPDIRECTINPUTDEVICE8 dinkbd;
BYTE keystate[256];
DIDATAFORMAT dfi;

void init_dinput(HINSTANCE hInst, HWND hWnd)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = DirectInput8Create(hInst, DIRECTINPUT_VERSION, IID_IDirectInput8, (void **)&din, NULL);
    hr = din->CreateDevice(GUID_SysKeyboard, &dinkbd, NULL);
    hr = dinkbd->SetDataFormat(&c_dfDIKeyboard);
    // share the keybdb and collect even when not the active application
    hr = dinkbd->SetCooperativeLevel(hWnd, DISCL_NONEXCLUSIVE | DISCL_BACKGROUND);
}

void detect_input(void)
{
    dinkbd->Acquire();
    dinkbd->GetDeviceState(256, keystate);
}

void clean_dinput(void)
{
    dinkbd->Unacquire();
    din->Release();
}

void print_state()
{
    WCHAR pState[4096] = L"";
    WCHAR temp[32];

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (keystate[i] != 0)
        {
            wsprintf (temp, L"%d(%d) ", i, keystate[i]);
            lstrcat(pState, temp);
        }
    }
    if (lstrlen(pState) != 0)
    {
        lstrcat(pState, L"\n");
        OutputDebugString(pState);
    }
}
```